# Adding or summing up numbers in each row in Perl

Tags: perl, sum

I want to add numbers in each row.
For example my row have following no,

```
@lines = ("1 .2 .3 .4 .5","2  .7 .8 .8  .10 ","  3 .12 .13  .14 .15");
```

I want to add numbers each row separately. The ***first digit*** (1, 2 and 3) in each line is the row number, which I ***do not want to include*** in summation.

I tried :

```
($total+=$_) for @temp[1..$#temp];
print "The row adds up to $total";
```

It gave me total for last row i.e 3rd row =.54

Please suggest me how to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: Based on your username, I'm guessing this is Perl. I've added a tag for clarity.

Comment: Isn't the 3rd row adding up to 54 correct? `12+13+14+15=54`

Comment: this single line of code is a perfect example for why i dislike perl as a programming language.

Comment: @Kaii What, you dislike for loops?

Answer (score 3):

Simply split each string on whitespace (the default for `split`) and use `splice` to extract all but the first element. Using `map` produces one long list of numbers to be added. The code looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = ("1 .2 .3 .4 .5", "2  .7 .8 .8  .10 ", "  3 .12 .13  .14 .15");

my $total;
$total += $_ for map { my @f = split; splice @f, 1; } @lines;

print $total;
```

**output**

```
4.34
```

---

**EDIT**

My apologies - I have only just noticed that you want the total for each string separately. Here is my solution for that

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = ("1 .2 .3 .4 .5","2  .7 .8 .8  .10 ","  3 .12 .13  .14 .15");

print "$_\n" for map {
  my @f = split;
  my $total;
  $total += $_ for splice @f, 1;
  $total;
} @lines;
```

**output**

```
1.4
2.4
0.54
```

Comment: Is `my $total;` just short version of `my $total = 0;`..? Isn't better to initialize the `$total` explicitly with zero, so it is more readable for everyone? Or is that some kind of optimization? Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: @stackoverflow: Perl is quite happy incrementing an undefined value. I prefer to declare variables that way so that I can distinguish between an untouched variable and one with a value of zero.

Comment: @downvoters: if there is a problem with my solution please let me know so that I have a chance to fix it.

Comment: `$total += $_ for splice @{[split]}, 1;` without `my @f = split;`

Comment: @stackoverflow: I dislike that sort of hack intensely and much prefer to use a temp variable. Perl is broken in that respect.

Comment: So you like `my $total;` but not my hack? Okay... Try test your code with modified input `@lines = ("1 .2 .3 .4 .5","2  .7 .8 .8  .10 ","  3 .12 .13  .14 .15","4");`

Comment: @stackoverflow: that is a strange extension of the data in the question, but my code produces a total of zero for the new string with only a row number, as you could have found for yourself. This conversation is over.

Comment: It does not return zero, but `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at...` with `use strict; use warnings;` (as you have those in your code). Over now.

Answer (score 2):

Actually 0.54 is the correct sum for the 3rd row imho.
Here a code snippet that computes the sum for all 3 rows.

```
@lines = ("1 .2 .3 .4 .5","2  .7 .8 .8  .10 ","  3 .12 .13  .14 .15");

foreach (@lines) {
        @row=split;

        $total=0;
        $total+=$_ for @row[1..$#row];

        print "Result $row[0]: $total\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Result 1: 1.4
Result 2: 2.4
Result 3: 0.54
```